# Flutter app is not running on real iOS device

Tags: ios, ipad, flutter

I have a mobile app in Flutter, it works fine on Android and iOS simulators as well as real devices (except only real iPads with iOS 12.0 and above)

The problem is with running the app in iPad - after the launch I see a white screen for 5 seconds, than a black screen for 3 seconds and that's the finish. The app is not running further. 
It even does not show a launching screen.

I am testing in Firebase Test Lab and I have done flutter upgrade before every build of product.
And this is my flutter doctor:

```
    flutter doctor       
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-GB)
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    [✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    [!] Android Studio (not installed)
    [!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

    ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Do you have any ideas what could it be?

Comment: Are you using Firebase? Have you configured it properly with your iOS app?

Comment: Is this with release or debug builds or both?

Comment: Enable trusted developer on general in setting.

Comment: Try to compile the app and install it in the device, instead of being the `run`command

Comment: @MohammadRF - Firebase is configured properly since the test is run and completed without any issues. However, when I watch video of test I see what I have described: white and black screens only

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this is for mode created by Product -> Build For -> Testing

Comment: @RashiduzzamanKhan is it possible to enable this mode ("Trusted developer") within the Xcode settings? I found that only on real device you can do this but I use Firebase Test Lab, hence, I cannot modify basic mode

Comment: @Vanethos The problem is that the issue is with iOS 12.0 and above, not a special device. I tried different iPads in Firebase Test Lab and the outcome is the same

Comment: @MarySeleznova on a terminal window see the flutter logs with `flutter logs`, is there an error that shows up when the app is killed?

Comment: Could you confirm if this is still happening on the [latest Flutter version](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)? Also found a related issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52930) and [Apple Developer's Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671213)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is an [open bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52930) about crashes that occurs on iPhones with the memory of 1GB or lower on most iOS 12. I suggest to upgrade your Flutter version to the latest. As of this writing, the [latest version is 2.10.3](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos) in stable channel.